# Django Channels Routing não funcionando

Tags: python, django, django-channels

Queria que as pessoas acessassem meu URL normalmente como antes (de instalar o channels) `localhost/home/minha-slug` e detectasse as mensagens do socket dentro dessa rota. Quero criar Groups para não ficar enviando mensagem para todos do site, e sim quem estiver na página.

**Meu Routing:**

```
home_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_add, path=r'^/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)'),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_message, path=r'^/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)'),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect, path=r'^/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)'),
]

channel_routing = [
    include(home_routing, path=r'^/home')
]
```

Meu consumer:

```
from channels import Group
import json

# Connected to websocket.connect
def ws_add(message, slug):
    # Accept the connection
    print(slug)
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    # Add to the chat group
    Group("room-%s" % slug).add(message.reply_channel)

# Connected to websocket.receive
def ws_message(message, slug):
    print(slug)
    Group("room-%s" % slug).send({
        "text": "oi"
    })


# Connected to websocket.disconnect
def ws_disconnect(message, slug):
    Group("room-%s" % slug).discard(message.reply_channel)
```

Aqui aparece que conecta no chat normalmente, mas parece que não envia/recebe mensagem. Alguém sabe onde estou errando ou outra maneira de trabalhar com groups/channels?

Obrigado.